# Direct equivalent of Express "next" function in Hapi.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hapi.js

I've read the documentation and also searched on this site, and not found any solutions to this, so hopefully someone can help me. I am building an app with Hapi, which I haven't used before, and in certain cases I'd like to skip a route that has been matched (for example, to go on to the 404 route) dependent on certain logic. Here's an example of how I'd do it using the `next` function in Express:

```
app.get("/example/files/:filename", function(req, res, next) {
    var file = cache.get(req.params.filename);

    if (!file) {
        let err = new Error(`Cannot retrieve file [${ filename }].`); // ES6 block scope and template literals
        err.statusCode = 404;
        return next(err);
    }

    // do other stuff with file here
});

app.use(function(err, req, res) {
    res.render("error", {
        message: err.message,
        statusCode: err.statusCode
    });
});
```

I can implement the same thing in Hapi, but don't know how to skip the route:

```
server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/example/files/{filename}",
    handler: (request, reply) => { // ES6 "arrow function" syntax
        var file = cache.get(request.params.filename);

        if (!file) {
            let err = new Error(`Cannot retrieve file [${ filename }].`);
            err.statusCode = 404;
            return ?????;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `return reply().code(404)` or even better `return reply(Boom.notFound('Can't find file...'))`. https://github.com/hapijs/boom

Comment: Also don't use arrow functions for route handlers. hapi relies on them having a bindable `this`, it will trip you up later.

Comment: That works, but only sends an empty 404 response, rather than skipping to the next route handler, which may contain lots of logic I want to run, so I would like to do the latter, if possible (maybe the only way is to save the error handler function and re-reference it from other routes, which seems a bit messy in comparison to Express' `next` function too). Thanks for the note about arrow functions though.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the next route handler" in hapi. One request is matched to one or no route handlers. If you're looking for a pipeline similar to express' middleware look into hapi's extension points or prerequisites. http://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle and http://hapijs.com/api#route-prerequisites

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway.